# set background color from start to end char position

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, caret

What would be an easy way to set the background color of all characters from some start to an end position in Java.

```
Eg:
red background from position D(4) to J(10)
String alpha = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

Many thanks in advance.

Edit:
Oh no, 2 '-'? Ok here is what I'm doing.

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
textArea.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, 16));
//then I want red background from position D(4) to J(10)
```

Comment: In what sort of control? The string itself has no formatting.

Comment: In Java?  How are you showing this string?  Do you mean JavaScript?

Comment: @Matthew Gilliard: This is almost certainly Java (with the exception of single quotes and no semicolon).

Comment: The context makes a difference.  The solution is different if this is in a JLabel, JTable, JTextPane, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please read [Using Text Components](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) and tons [examples](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/TextArea.htm) for that

look here for [excelent workaround](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/rectangle-painter/)

Answer (score 0):

Split the `String` into 3 separate `String`s.

```
String a = alpha.substring(0,4);
String b = alpha.substring(4,11);
String c = alpha.substring(11);
```

Then display `a`,`b`, and `c` next to each other while only formatting `b` as desired.